# AngularJS show result of HTTP request inside directive in template

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-directive

I'm trying to make GET request the first time I load an AngularJS (1.6) directive and show its result in the directive's template.

What I am trying so far is the following:

JS:

```
app.directive("myDirective", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        attrs: {
            foo : String,
            onResponse : function(response){
                this.foo = response.data; 
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/my-directive.html',

        compile: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'my/url'
            }).then(
                attrs.onResponse
            );
        }
    }
}]);
```

the HTML template:

```
<div id="my-directive">
    foo: <span>attrs.foo</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to do what I wanted by adding a controller:

```
 app.directive("myDirective", ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            controller: "myDirectiveController",
            templateUrl: 'templates/my-directive.html'
        }
    }]);
```

where

```
app.controller('myDirectiveController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.foo;
    $scope.onResponse = function(response){
       $scope.foo= response.data;
    }
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'my/url'
        }).then(
            $scope.onResponse
        );
});
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<div id="my-directive">
    foo: <span>{{foo}}</span>
</div>
```

Probably this is not the proper way to do it but it works.. Any suggestions are welcome!